# Include enumeration within detailed java doc class description

Tags: java, documentation, javadoc

I am describing some classes using JavaDoc in two steps short description and a developed version of the that description:

```
/*
 *
 * This class will be used to do things.
 * <p>
 *    Here I am expanding the short description  ...
 * </p>
 * ...
 */
 Class myClass 
 {
     ...
     ...
     ...
 }
```

I wonder whether is it possible to include listings and enumerations within the detailed description so the result should be something like:

```
/*
 *
 * This class will be used to do things.
 * <p>
 *    Here I am expanding the short description  ...
 *    * List element 1
 *    * List element 2
 * </p>
 * ...
 */
 Class myClass 
 {
     ...
     ...
     ...
 }
```

But generating enumerations and/or lists in the HTML output of JavaDoc.
Should I use HTML elements such as `<ul>` and `<ol>` in the JavaDoc comments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, HTML elements like

```
 *  <ul>
 *    <li>Item1</li>
 *    <li>Item2</li>
 *  </ul>
```

are perfectly OK in javadoc. Have a look at the standard Java API classes for more examples.

Answer (score 0):

I tested my JavaDoc comments and found that HTML tokens are included in the generated documentation:

```
/**
 * Class intended ....................
 * <p>
 *     Each object ...................
 *     <ul>
 *        <li>Item1</li>
 *        <li>Item2</li>
 *     </ul>
 * </p>
 * @author Pablo.Francisco.Pérez.Hidalgo
 * @since 2013-03-22
 */
```

[image]